# Cannot fetch result set from stored procedure using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

My Ruby program simply wants to invoke a stored procedure (which will do some calculations) and return a result set which I want to email using Ruby code.  Kindly note that I am not using Rails, just plain Ruby and mysql2 gems.

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "mysql2",
  :host  => "localhost",
  :database => "<mydb>",
  :username => "<myusername>",
  :password => "<mypassword>"
)

class Rubyist < ActiveRecord::Base  
end

rubyist = Rubyist.new
puts rubyist.connection.execute("CALL ruby_routine")
```

The following error is returned

```
    Mysql2::Error: PROCEDURE students.ruby_routine can't return a result set in the given context: CALL ruby_routine (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Now I have Googled for this and found links but they are for a Rails app.  How do I do this in pure Ruby?

Comment: Try adding `:flags => 131072` to the connection params hash. Reference: http://spectator.in/2011/03/12/rails2-mysql2-and-stored-procedures/

Comment: Agreed. Don't shy away from the rails-related answers. You're using ActiveRecord anyway, and any posts on this topic aren't likely to be about any other component.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I just added the :flags => 131702 and tried again.  Still same error.

Comment: What is that "students"? Please, write the exact code that you have. Also, it should be require 'activerecord'.

Comment: @Nobita the "students" is the name of the database.  Also 'activerecord' gives **cannot load such a file error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem raises from the mysql2 connector that is used in ActiveRecord.  As the guys from mysql2 say in their docs:

> You can also retrieve multiple result sets. For this to work you need
>   to connect with flags Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS. Using multiple
>   result sets is normally used when calling stored procedures that
>   return more than one result set

So, by default is not set.  Right, so ideally if you were using the mysql2 adapter directly (without ActiveRecord), you would pass the flag like this:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS )
```

However, since you are using ActiveRecord, you need to overwrite the mysql2 connector.  Something like this could do the trick.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    # Establishes a connection to the database that's used by all Active Record objects.
    def self.mysql2_connection(config)
      config[:username] = 'root' if config[:username].nil?

      if Mysql2::Client.const_defined? :FOUND_ROWS
        config[:flags] = Mysql2::Client::FOUND_ROWS | Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
      end

      client = Mysql2::Client.new(config.symbolize_keys)
      options = [config[:host], config[:username], config[:password], config[:database], config[:port], config[:socket], 0]
      ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.new(client, logger, options, config)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just changed the mysql2_adapter file to take in Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS also.  It worked like a charm!  Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is syntax. Try moving the "establish_connection" method inside the class "rubyist".